# Check status thread is activated or no

Tags: android

Hi guys i have a Thread into a Activity.
I want know the status of the thread when i run the Activity...
Is possible know the status of thread?
Example:

if thread not running, start now.

Whenever i run the Activity, the thread start :(

Thread:

```
  public void callAsynchronousTask(Timer timer, final ToggleButton btnAtterraDecolla,
        final ToggleButton btnRitardo, final ToggleButton btnImbarco)
  {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    isTimerRunning = true;

    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {       
        @Override
        public void run() {             
            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {       
                    try {
                        tTask aTask =  new tTask(); //THIS IS ASYNCTASK

                        if(btnAtterraDecolla.isChecked())
                            LOL(1,AoP,btnAtterraDecolla);    

                        if(btnRitardo.isChecked())
                            LOL(2,AoP,btnRitardo);  

                        if(btnImbarco.isChecked())
                            LOL(3,AoP,btnImbarco);
                        aTask.execute();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, TEMPO_ESECUZIONE_THREAD); /
}
```

In onDestroy()

```
    @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopUpdates(btnAtterraDecolla,btnRitardo,btnImbarco);
    super.onDestroy();

}
private void stopUpdates(ToggleButton btnAtterraDecolla,ToggleButton btnRitardo,ToggleButton btnImbarco) {

    if(!btnAtterraDecolla.isChecked() && !btnRitardo.isChecked() && !btnImbarco.isChecked()){
        if (isTimerRunning) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer.purge();
            timer = null;
            isTimerRunning = false;
        }
    }
}

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
....callAsynchronousTask(...)
```

And here i want stop the thread ONLY IF btn1,btn2,btn3 is NOT checked!

There is a solution for this problem?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are some way can check the Thread properties

You able to check Thread is Alive() by

```
Thread.isAlive() ,
```

method it return boolean.

You able to found running thread run by

```
Thread.currentThread().getName()
```

Comment: Sorry i don't understand... can you make me an example?

Comment: Sorry is a timer... i want check the status of timer... is on or off